# How to create three dot button on the top right of an item on an android listview?

Tags: android, listview, menu

Like this

[image]

If you click the button a menu will drop down. I use `ListView` to implement, but I don't know how to attach the three-dot-button and add a pop-up menu.

Here is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMain"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And the screenshot of my app:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2ko2ctfn5ohmf9/Screenshot_2013-09-10-15-43-57.png

Comment: an image with on click, show a container overlay for menu

Comment: @AshaSoman he has already posted.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a `ImageView` with the correct PNG (you'll have to draw the image yourself on photoshop, paint, GIMP or any other graphical editor) and use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to make the popup.

here is a simple example on how to do a PopupWindow (got it from here http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }});
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 0, -0);
```

}